# React App get automatic refresh while scrolling up in mobile device

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I cannot post a code as it is policy of our firm. I have a wishlist page where you can see different named wishlist which user has created such as wihslist1, wishlist2 and so on. So what we want is when you click on any wishlist it will open it up and give us items in it. now we can have lot of item but all of the items are being paginated. so when you reach the bottom of the page and the moment you start going up while scrolling the app get automatic refresh and instead of sticking to the particular wishlist that we open it will lead us to wishlist where every wishlists are available.

So I do not want to refresh or go back to the wishlists categories area, i want to able to prevent this refrshing and able to scroll up untill and unless I click on back button or do some hard back using device.

I have this component as react class component,

I am not able to figure out what is triggering that refresh upon scrolling up.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue with adding additional state which only responsible for mobile view wishlist rendering. Once this flag or state is remain true we want to check if any activewishlist is there or not if yes then we will keep checking these 2 condition and display this active wishlist. The issue with the scroll is now settled up. Because the state that was resetting everything while scrolling now has to depend on these above 2 conditions and so on component did update I am checking this 2 conditions. hence this problem was solved. if someone needs more clarified detail let me know. I have given an abstract idea how I solved.